# Quantization of mobilenet-ssd

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, deep-learning

I wanted to quantize (change all the floats into INT8) a ssd-mobilenet model and then want to deploy it onto my raspberry-pi. So far, I have not yet found any thing which can help me with it. Any help would be highly appreciated. 
I saw tensorflow-lite but it seems it only supports android and iOS. 
Any library/framweork is acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution? I trained the model but it's in floats

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow Lite now has support for the Raspberry Pi via Makefiles. [Here's the shell script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/build_rpi_lib.sh). Regarding Mobilenet-SSD, you can get details on how to use it with TensorFlow Lite in [this blog post](https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/07/accelerated-training-and-inference-with.html) (and [here](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193))

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [TensorRT library](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#work-with-qat-networks).

One of the features of the library is quantization.
In general mobilenets are difficult to quantize (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.09602.pdf) but the library should do a good work